How to load a map for IFC model in Autodesk Forge Viewer and position it at the exact location
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJi6jqCLt0Q
please check the above video . when i click on load map is loading and the model is loading at the exact location of the model
iam using autodesk forge viewer.
iam using version .please guide me how can i achieve the above requirement.
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"


Please refer to the blog Add Mapbox, Google Maps into Forge Viewer for a complete implementation.
